# Scraping and navigating to links to get more info

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

Not sure if what I am trying to do is possible...but here goes. I am trying to navigate and scrape info from this table (simplified)...

```
> <tr class="transaction odd" id="transaction_7"><td><a
> href="/show_customer/11111">Erin</a></td></tr> <tr class="transaction
> even" id="transaction_6"><td><a
> href="/show_customer/2222">Jack</a></td></tr> <tr class="transaction
> odd" id="transaction_5"><td><a
> href="/show_customer/3333">Carl</a></td></tr> <tr class="transaction
> even" id="transaction_4"><td><a
> href="/show_customer/4444">Kelly</a></td></tr>
```

This is the code I used to scrape the table and output into a csv...works well.

```
columns = ["User Name", "Source", "Staff", "Location", "Attended On", "Used", "Date"]
table = []

for row in table_1.find_all('tr'):
    tds  = row.find_all('td')
    try:
        data = [td.get_text() for td in tds]
        for field,value in zip(columns, data):
            print("{}: {}".format(field, value))
        table.append(data)
    except:
        print("Bad string value")


import csv

with open("myfile.csv", "wb") as outf:

    outcsv = csv.writer(outf)

    # header row
    outcsv.writerow(columns)

    # data
    outcsv.writerows(table)
```

What I need to do is navigate to each link in the table like this

```
<a> href="/show_customer/11111">Erin</a>
```

and grab the customers email address that is in this html form

```
<div class="field">
   <div class = "label">Email</div>
   <p>XXXX@email.com</p>
   </div>
```

And add that to the relevant row in my csv.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to make a http request for every `href` in the `td`. This is how you would modify your existing code to do that:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

for row in table_1.find_all('tr'):
    tds  = row.find_all('td')
    # Get all the hrefs to make http request
    links = row.find_all('a').get('href')
    try:
        data = [td.get_text() for td in tds]
        for field,value in zip(columns, data):
            print("{}: {}".format(field, value))
        # For every href make a request, get the page,
        # create a BS object
        for link in links:
            link_soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(link))

            # Use link_soup BS instance to get the email 
            # by navigating the div and p and add it to your data

        table.append(data)
    except:
        print("Bad string value")
```

Note that your `href` is relative to the website's url. So after you extract the `href` you would have to prepend it with the website's url to form a valid url

Comment: Thanks for your Help! I am getting the error 'AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'' on the Links...Maybe I just dont have the base level knowledge for this yet...any pointers there?

Comment: Its still passing the same error. Thanks for your efforts, though. I really do appreciate it!